# Using Flexinol Or Muscle Wire To Control Paper Flower Petal With Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, wires, components

I am relatively new to Arduino and I am looking to use flexinol or muscle wire to control flower petals. I think I will need to control 4 sets of the wire. I have totally no idea of how to wire the components together, if I will need to get additional parts like a transistor or battery, and what type/thickness of wire I should get.

Comment: this question is not Arduino specific ... you would have the same question if you were using a Raspbery Pi or any other microcontroller

Comment: And you haven't given any information about your actual hardware. Please provide a link to the product, that you want to use (somewhere, where you can look at the datasheet of the product)

Comment: If you aren't willing to do some brain work to figure out the problem, why should we help you?